# remap escape key with Ukelele

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I have the following keyboard:

[image]

I would like the change the top left key from "escape" to @/# and map Escape on "option + @".

So I created a new keymap with Ukelele and installed it:

[image]

The problem is the escape key has steel the same behavior, when I press the top left key it steel execute has escape key instead of "@/#"

I can confirm my new map is installed (I replaced the A by a K and I have a K when I press A).

There is something special to do to replace the Escape key ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of Ukelele, it doesn't remap 'functionality', just 'characters'.

To remap functionality, you're more likely to need [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)

Comment: 1) I can map escape to @, but not CAPS + Escape to #
2) If I don't have to have a tool running to map the key, it's better
3) Why Hukelele display the Escape key if we can't edit it ?

Comment: 1. None of this information is in your original question. We cannot answer what you do not ask. 2. CapsLock is not a modifier key; it's not waiting for a second key to combine with. 3.You'd have to ask the developer of Ukelele.